# UDP Address already in use?

Tags: java, networking, udp

I am following the UDP tutorials at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html ,I have copied all the code and compiled it, now If I compile the client first and then the server, the server prints this out in console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at QuoteServerThread.<init>(QuoteServerThread.java:19)
at MulticastServerThread.<init>(MulticastServerThread.java:10)
at MulticastServer.main(MulticastServer.java:3)
```

QuoteServerThread line 19 is

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(12345);
```

MulticastServerThread line 10 is

```
public MulticastServerThread() throws IOException {
    super("MulticastServerThread"); // line 10
}
```

MulticastServer line 3 is

```
public class MulticastServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        new MulticastServerThread().start(); // line 3
    }
}
```

If I start the server first, then the client, the client prints out this in console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
at java.net.MulticastSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.MulticastSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
at MulticastClient.main(MulticastClient.java:9)
```

MulticastClient line 9 is

```
MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(12345);
```

Looking at the errors, it seems to me that it is something to do with listening to ports, how can I go about fixing this?

Canvas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely because you are already running an instance of the server. Only one server can listen on a given port at a time. Check to see if you are already running an instance (if you are using Eclipse, you should see this in the command window) and terminate it before running another instance.

Though it is also possible that a stream was not shut down properly. If you are running an IDE, restarting the IDE should fix the problem, though occasionally I have had to restart my computer. Probably a better solution to fix this, but that is what has worked for me.

Comment: Just closed and re-opened Eclipse and still get the same errors :(

Comment: @Canvas try your computer? If you haven't changed anything between the client and server from the tutorial, it shouldn't be a code error.

Comment: I did change the port, that is about it, but ok, will give it a go in abit :)

Comment: I redid the code and it now works, what I noticed was, the QuoteServerThread can not use the same port, so my Client, Server and QuoteServer was all on port 12345, this is what caused the error, so I changed my QuoteServer to 12345, and the Server and Client to 4446, and everything works fine :)

Comment: "Only one server can listen on a given port at a time."  If I create a DatagramSocket on my server and on my client, and run both on the same machine, does that exemplify what you are describing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Use netstat coomand  to view which application is using that port.
  Then use tasklist and taskkill to kill the application at that port.

Comment: See the already-accepted answer to this question; the problem was that the client and server were trying to listen to the same port. This could have been a helpful comment (rather than an answer) before that information was discovered, though.

Comment: 1. When I answered there was no accepted answer. 2. My answer still holds. Sometimes users start two seprate tomcat instance for example for different application which can cause this issue. Hence netstat is a quick way to find out. 3. Sometimes users thisnk they have closed a running instance by simply closing the terminal while the instance is still running in the background. So accepted answer will not work if the app was started using terminal and through IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what happens is that you have on the client side two wires that connect to the same port. When you receive a message from the server, the client machine does not know what thread to redirect the message since they have two different DatagramSocket tips pointing to the same port

Answer (score 0):

1. Open TaskManager
2. Search for a process name starting with OpenJDK.
3. End/kill the process.
4. Now run your program again.

You don't need to restart your IDE.