# I always face This Problem java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind

Tags: flutter, dart

I am sorry, I have searched but seem that all the answers don't fix my problem. I got this error when trying to run my flutter app.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: does `flutter clean` solve in this case?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/15096143/10157127

Comment: i Check using, flutter clean, flutter pub get, gradlew clean, all this command does not help  me